# Is every measure finitely additive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The answer is yes because for disjoint $A_i, i=1,2,...n$

$\mu(A_1\cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n) = \mu(A_1\cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup ...) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu(A_i) + \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \mu(\emptyset) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu(A_i)$

Correct?

Comment: I think this is indeed a requirement for measures (in fact, the requirement is for countable disjoint sets, which is even stronger). See [the definition on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition).

Comment: You are correct. The word "finitely" can be left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your reasoning is correct. Assume we have a measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$, then we define a (positive) measure to be a function $\mu: \Sigma \to [0, \infty]$ for which the following holds:
\begin{align*}
&\mu(\emptyset) = 0 \\
&\mu(E) \geq 0 \text{ for all } E \in \Sigma
\end{align*}
and for a **countable** collection $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of **pairwise disjoint** sets in $\Sigma$ we have that
\begin{align*}
\mu \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu (E_i)
\end{align*}
Your reasoning shows that countable additivity implies finite additivity, which makes sense, doesn't it?